# Eclipse variables

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-cdt

Trying to manage post-build steps in Eclipse CDT project. Trying to copy newly builded file to directory `~/destination` .

I could do following:

```
cp ${BuildArtifactFileBaseName}.so ~/destination
```

But I would like to escape from hardcoded parts there. For this reason I need to know:

```
Artifact extension Eclipse variable
Custom defined destination path variable
```

Where I can define custom variable for `~/destination` ?

Where I can find whole list of Eclipse variables? 
Will they be different for Java and C++ projects?

Answer (score 0):

The Eclipse CDT build variables can be found at `Window -> Preferences -> C/C++ -> Build ->Build Variables`.

To see all variables, check the `Show system variables` checkbox.

Use the `Add` button on the `Build Variables` screen to add a new variable.

I don't have experience with Java on Eclipse, but probably there's an equivalent menu when compiling Java.